# Does VS Form Designer waste resources repeating fonts?

Tags: winforms, performance, visual-studio, designer

When I create a form, usually it contains a large number of controls that require a font. Generally, I will use at most 3 different fonts on the form. But I note when I look in the designer that it creates a separate font object for each control.

Is this as big a waste of memory as it looks like? Would it be significantly more efficient to create just one font object for each font used, and set the fonts for each control to the appropriate already-existing font object?

This is not about changing the designer code. I really want to know what would be best when adding controls to a form myself.

Comment: If you don't assign a new font to `Font` property of a control, it uses font of it's parent. So it's enough to assign new font only to the controls that you prefer to have different font and let the other controls use their parent font.

Comment: Fonts are cached.  If you use new Font(...) a second time with the same arguments then you'll use the same underlying physical font.  Just try it yourself by creating one million Font objects in a loop to feel good about it.  The cache [is here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/misc/GDI/WindowsGraphicsCacheManager.cs,03ac592834a9ebca).

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks. That is what I was curious about: if there was something going on behind-the-scenes that made it cleaner than it appeared in a naive reading.